# Заменить extend на list comprehension

Tags: python

Можно ли заменить этот код:

```
nums = []
for i in range(int(input())):
    nums.extend(map(int, input().split()))
```

на `list comprehension` ?
Предполагал, что можно сделать так:
`nums=[*map(int, input().split()) for i in range(int(input()))]`
но python говорит:
`SyntaxError: iterable unpacking cannot be used in comprehension`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
nums = [i
        for _ in range(int(input()))
        for i in map(int, input().split())]
```